# ¿Cómo buscar palabra en vertical?

Tags: c

Necesito buscar la ubicación de una palabra como si fuera una sopa de letras, en forma horizontal, vertical y en diagonal.

Por ejemplo la palabra "kl", aparece en el tablero, a partir de la celda del renglón 2 y columna 0, leyendo hacia la "derecha". En el caso de la palabra "dk" aparece a partir de la celda del reglón 1, columna 0 y leyendo hacia "abajo". En el caso de la palabra "dl" aparece a partir de la celda del reglón 1, columna 0 y leyendo hacia el "sureste". Pero la palabra "al", no se encuentra en el tablero, si consideramos únicamente los 3 sentidos válidos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define REN 10
#define COL 10
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int renglon, columna;
    char caracter, aux;
    int tam;
    char matriz[REN][COL];
    char palabra1[11];
    char palabra2[11];
    char palabra3[11];
    int bandera,contador,longitud;
    
    gets(palabra1);
    gets(palabra2);
    gets(palabra3);
    
    scanf ("%d",&tam);
    scanf ("%c",&aux);
    
    //CICLO PARA LA CAPTURA DE DATOS
    for(renglon=0; renglon<tam; renglon++){
        for (columna=0; columna<tam; columna++){
            scanf ("%c", &matriz[renglon][columna]);
            scanf ("%c", &aux);
        }
    }

    for(renglon=0; renglon<tam; renglon++){
        for (columna=0; columna<tam; columna++){
            if (matriz[renglon][columna] == palabra1[0]){
            //comenzamos a buscar la palabra1
            //BUSCAR A LA DERECHA (IMPLEMENTAMOS UN CICLO QUE BUSQUE A LA DERECHA LA SUIGUENTE LETRA DE LA PALABRA)
                longitud= strlen(palabra1);
                bandera=1;
                for (contador=1;contador<longitud && columna+contador<tam; contador++){//controla no exceder a la longitud de la palabra
                    if (matriz [renglon][columna+contador] == palabra1[contador]){
                        bandera=0; // si la bandera cambia a cero es por que la palabra no se encuentra a la deracha
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //verificar el codigo cuando termine
                //si todos los caracteres coincidieron
                if (bandera==1  && contador==longitud ){
                    //imprimir las coordenadas
                    printf ("%c:%d %d derecha,",palabra1, renglon,columna);
                }
            //BUSCAR EN DIAGONAL AL SURESTE
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
            //BUSCAR HACIA ABAJO
                
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No veo una pregunta aquí. Necesitas algo, claro, pero no dices qué te detiene.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos esta sopa de letras:

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
> X X X X X X X 0
> X P A T A T A 1
> X X X I X X X 2
> X X R T X X X 3
> X X X A X X X 4
> X X X N T X X 5
> X X X X X A X 6
> ```

Tenemos que las coordenadas de Patata, Titán y Rata son:

- Patata: {1,1}, {2,1}, {3,1}, {4,1}, {5,1}, {6,1}.
- Titán: {3,1}, {3,2}, {3,3}, {3,4}, {3,5}.
- Rata: {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {5,6}.

Podemos observar que las coordenadas varían siguiendo un vector:

- Patata: {1,0}.
- Titán: {0,1}.
- Rata: {1,1}.

Este vector, si se suma a las coordenadas de la primera letra, te da la posición de la siguiente letra de la palabra. Si creamos un objeto vector, podemos usarlo para buscar palabras en la dirección que queramos:

```
typedef struct { int x, y; } vector;

void busca(vector posicion, vector direccion, char sopa[ANCHO][ALTO], char *datos)
{
    for (int i = 0; posicion.x < ANCHO && posicion.y < ALTO; posicion.x += direccion.x, posicion.y += direccion.y, ++i)
        datos[i] = sopa[posicion.y][posicion.x];
}
```

Por ejemplo, este código mostraría `En la posicion [2,3] direccion [1,1] encontramos RATA`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ANCHO 7
#define ALTO 7

#if ANCHO > ALTO
#define MAYOR ANCHO
#else
#define MAYOR ALTO
#endif

typedef struct { int x, y; } vector;

void busca(vector posicion, vector direccion, char sopa[ANCHO][ALTO], char *datos)
{
    for (int i = 0; posicion.x < ANCHO && posicion.y < ALTO; posicion.x += direccion.x, posicion.y += direccion.y, ++i)
        datos[i] = sopa[posicion.y][posicion.x];
}

int main(void)
{
    char sopa[ALTO][ANCHO] = 
    {
        'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'P', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'A',
        'X', 'X', 'X', 'I', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'X', 'R', 'T', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'X', 'X', 'N', 'T', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X',
    };

    char palabra[MAYOR  + 1];
    vector posicion, direccion;

    posicion.x = 2;
    posicion.y = 3;
    direccion.x = 1;
    direccion.y = 1;
    memset(palabra, 0, MAYOR + 1);
    busca(posicion, direccion, sopa, palabra);
    printf("En la posicion [%d,%d] direccion [%d,%d] encontramos %s\n",
        posicion.x, posicion.y,
        direccion.x, direccion.y,
        palabra);

    return 0;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que si no se sabe el tamaño de la palabra, leerás palabras como `TITANX`. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VPPT9swGD3Hf8UnqkJKs6odhx1CkSo0aZM2mBAHpiwHYztgKbWj2EWNUP/2YjuZkzas7AwXy3nfr/c9v5BPJMfiYbsdcEHyFWVwrjTlcvJ4gbpQycWDxdCAsowLBoury2/X8KX9/nFrP01R1sQuHOYTfi5@X9/UITRguWL7EZfMBOUZQroqmImCGbwiGp6BCw3rCKoYNvDEiJZljNCT5BTuV4rgsMagkIoTLkXUJAHlJSM1Qh5xCUoWOHEk0sROTBv8lGIt1Qg9oyAzZaGdx2EO09j3nKzhvFnt@LhFK4uaTjuJ43k7eWJ4d7J3QlUE4zEfoSBw8xOempmOY1uRtvd1GqMNQpbcEnMRWgEc585udqlmQ9MLBSYanNydRHDw8Em/7LGwx23v9kqn7//u5I4bX38g6c5Peivpqtfu4HYLn7QxdqlVKnCO70uc1K6DMcyMqEHPP/6NbGHnZecwiztA1QCd1@4hlfMRCpZsqZgOGwIRTKPG@obDyMRrJ79CIXJPG/2lbnML80PqLDz6KiDHnjYkQxoNadqWeoQJIoUu8VIqGKo/4sgq1@7VtaiN7Li361db5WnsKXP2tjLTnjKzj6DM531lzv7DM@9VmZLpVSmsFTbb7Qs)</kbd>.